# Como criar uma trigger mysql para dar baixa no estoque?

Tags: mysql

Primeiramente vou apresentar a estrutura do banco de dados:

Tabela Pedidos:

```
id
cliente
data
status
```

Tabela Itens:

```
id
produto
tamanho = Estoque.id
quantidade
pedido = Pedidos.id
```

Tabela Estoque

```
id
tamanho
quantidade
chave = Produto.id
```

Tabela Produto

```
id
codigo
nome
preco
```

Trata-se de uma loja de roupas, logo um produtos pode ter 1 ou N tamanhos e cada tamanho pode ter 0 ou N peças em estoque

Gostaria de criar uma trigger, para que ao atualizar o status do pedido para 3(Pago), atualiza-se a tabela estoque, dando baixa da quantidade de produtos comprados nesse pedido

seria algo como

> "update estoque set quantidade=(quantidade-itens.quantidade) where itens.id...

Aí não sei mais se o começo tem algum sentido tratando-se de mysql e nem como continuar após isso para que ocorra tudo corretamente...

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Problema recorrente , uma pesquisa no Google e você acha montes de exemplos praticamente prontos. https://www.google.com.br/search?q=mysql+triggers+controle+estoque&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:pt-BR:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=7dWtU4_ZI6ek8wesoIDQBA

Comment: leia http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151684/controle-de-estoque-trigger-no-mysql-vs-l%C3%B3gica-na-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php/151691#151691

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MySQL Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) não funciona para uma coluna da tabela mas sim para uma linha.

Assim sendo, terás que verificar se a linha contém novos valores e proceder em conformidade.

## Criar um *trigger*

A *syntax* para criar um *trigger* é relativamente simples:

```sql
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER baixaDeEstoque
AFTER UPDATE ON pedidos
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   --código aqui
END$$
```

## Criar um *trigger* verificando valores

Como pretendes reagir se o estado estiver a `pago`, deverás adicionar essa verificação no *trigger* fazendo uso de `NEW` e `OLD` que te dá o novo valor e o valor antigo respectivamente para a coluna indicada:

```sql
if NEW.minhaColuna <=> OLD.minhaColuna
```

Com a adição de uma confirmação onde avaliamos se o novo valor da coluna `status` é efectivamente `pago`. Isto porque se for um outro estado que tenha sido aplicado, não queremos dar baixa do estoque.

Optemos assim o seguinte código:

```sql
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER baixaDeEstoque
AFTER UPDATE ON pedidos
FOR EACH ROW
if (NEW.status <=> OLD.status) AND NEW.status = 'pago' 
BEGIN
   --código aqui
END$$
```

## Código Final

O teu código final ficaria algo deste género:

```sql
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE TRIGGER baixaDeEstoque
AFTER UPDATE ON pedidos
FOR EACH ROW
if NEW.status <=> OLD.status AND NEW.status = 'pago' 
BEGIN
   UPDATE estoque
   INNER JOIN itens ON estoque.id = itens.tamanho
   SET quantidade = quantidade-1
   WHERE itens.pedido = NEW.id;
END$$
```

Comment: Quase que exatamente oque eu precisava, só a quantidade atualiza de acordo com a quantidade de itens comprados... mas de resto era exatamente isso

Comment: Nesse caso, aconselho que faça esse controle via regra de negócio da sua aplicação. Basta criar um método e chama-lo ao finalizar a compra.