# Trigger no MySQL VS lógica na aplicação PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, engenharia-de-software, trigger

Estou fazendo sistema de controle de estoque, e eu gostaria de saber quais as vantagens e desvantagens entre duas formas de implementação para fazer a subtração do número no estoque após uma venda/saída.

1) Realizar um `update` direto na aplicação através de *script* em PHP?

2) Fazer via `trigger` na tabela vendas após `insert` pegar quantidade de produto que foi vendido e dar um `update` na tabela do produto no campo: `estoque = estoque - 1`

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de cada método?

Comment: Acho que minha resposta ficou meio indireta, não ficou claro para mim se você está escolhendo uma arquitetura geral que vai ser implementada ou se está discutindo um caso particular para implementar uma funcionalidade... Tipo, vou implementar a trigger so aqui no update do estoque ou vou colocar toda a regra de negócio no banco e só isso vai ficar aqui porque é mais rápido..

Comment: Você tem duas respostas. Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Não dá para afirmar qual é melhor. Depende da arquitetura de toda solução, da experiência da equipe, do objetivo, dá pra dizer até que é gosto.

Você pode garantir que colocará na aplicação sempre que for necessário? Não é difícil se a aplicação for construída da forma certa. Não é só possível, mas desejável que em toda aplicação haja um só lugar para fazer as operações e usar o algoritmo estabelecido onde precisar. Desta forma é possível criar até algoritmos diferentes para executar em circunstâncias diferentes. [Isso se faz com DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). Particularmente prefiro na aplicação.

Uma forma de ter algo cânone é usar o gatilho no banco de dados. Nem todo mundo gosta disso. Se tiver que fazer condicionalmente, pode ser mais complicado. Pode garantir que não haverá alguma situação que o gatilho não se aplica ou deve se aplicar de forma diferente?

Algumas pessoas dirão que no banco de dados há um controle de concorrência. Mas é possível fazer isso na aplicação também em uma transação só.

Isso faz parte das regras de negócio. Pode ler mais em [Regras de Negócio no Banco de Dados - quais as vantagens e desvantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15739/101). É quase uma duplicata.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada na resposta pra merecer -1?

Answer (score 5):

De um forma geral, evita-se espalhar logica de negócio em camadas distintas da aplicação. Imagine que outras pessoas vão dar manutenção no código, o que vai acontecer? O novo programador vai ter que rebolar um pouco pra perceber que a logica que atualiza a quantidade de estoque simplesmente não está na camada de código responsável por alterar o estoque, está na camada de dados.

Quando eu estudei engenharia de software, tinha uma frase interessante que era usada 'camada de dados é camada de dados/armazenamento, negócio é negócio'. mas, depois eu percebi que não é tão simples assim e que fazer o time manter a integridade conceitual de um projeto é realmente algo difícil, exige disciplina.

Neste caso mais específico, a performance com toda certeza vai ser algo a ser discutido, visto que retirar a trigger vai fazer com que o aplicativo tenha que realizar um acesso ao banco para fazer o update (ou outra ação) e isso geralmente é mais lento.

Você deve analisar os fatores principais que vão afetar seu projeto e quais foram as decisões de arquitetura que foram definidas no início para que as implementações pontuais de manutenção não destruam sua arquitetura mas, que também não destruam a performance.

Um artigo do Martin Fowler (uma referencia clássica em POO) pode lhe ajudar com tópicos ja discutidos, retirei um trecho do texto que talvez te dê uma visão:

> "With both of the first two, the database is used pretty much as a
>   storage mechanism. All we've done is asked for all the records from a
>   particular table with some very simple filtering. SQL is a very
>   powerful query language and can do much more than the simple filtering
>   that these examples use...."

Algo como: de forma geral, o banco de dados é um mecanismo para guardar dados, tudo que fazemos é solicitar um conjunto de dados com um critério particular de filtro. SQL é uma linguagem poderosa e pode fazer muito mais do que simplesmente filtrar ... - tradução livre.

Esse texto mostra a definição basica e entra na discussão dos aspectos maiores de utilização de logica na aplicação ou em instruções SQL, não é tão didático e assume que o leitor tenha experiência em certos cenários, mas, vai ajudar.

http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/dblogic.html

Existe um outro porém, não tão discutido, muitos aplicativos comerciais suportam mais de um banco de dados (Oracle, Mysql, SQL Server, etc), a "linguagem SQL" que cada um suporta vai variar de acordo com o fornecedor, bem como recursos que podem ser usados em conjunto com a linguagem escolhida para as outras camadas (PHP, asp.net, etc), logo, colocar as regras de negócio no banco, vai exigir uma estratégia mais complexa de manutenção de produto para vários databases, visto que as principais validações de um software são as regras de negócio e esse custo pode impactar diretamente no modelo de gerencia do produto.